# Spring controller gets invoked but returns 404

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a Spring Boot application. I have written a simple controller that gets invoked whenever the endpoint is hit, but it still returns status 404 and not the specified return value.

**HelloController**

```
@Controller
public class MessageRequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hit me!");
        return "Hello, you!";
    }
}
```

Now whenever I call `localhost:8080/hello`, I see the console log `"Hit me!"`, but `"Hello, you!"` is never returned. Postman outputs:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1516953147719,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/hello"
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.sergialmar.wschat"}) // this is the root package of everything
@EntityScan("com.sergialmar.wschat")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: as a sidenode, it doesn't actually produce `application/json`, does it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Change your method return a `ResponseEntity<T>`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
    System.out.println("Hit me!");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello, you!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

or change the controller to `RestController`

```
@RestController
public class MessageRequestController {...}
```

CURL

```
ubuntu:~$ curl -X GET localhost:8080/hello
Hello, you!
```

Answer (score 15):

Short version:

Annotate your endpoint method with [ResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) to bind the return value to the response body.

```
@Controller
public class MessageRequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hit me!");
        return "Hello, you!";
    }

}
```

You can instead annotate your class with [RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) instead of `Controller` to apply `ResponseBody` to each method of the class.

```
@RestController
public class MessageRequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello", produces = "application/json")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hit me!");
        return "Hello, you!";
    }

}
```

With @Controller, you use the default model-view from [Spring Web MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc), and you're actually telling spring to render the view called `Hello, you!.tml` from your resources directory (`src/main/resources/templates` for a Spring Boot project, if I remember correctly).

You can read [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-framework-restcontroller-vs-controller) for more information about the Spring MVC REST Workflow.

Once you're more familiar with those concepts, you can even further customize your endpoint method using [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-responseentity).

Answer (score 2):

As you see the "hit me", there's no mapping issue, but in your @RequestMapping annotation you specifie a produce type to "application/json" and you return a simple poor String not formatted and without any header('Content-Type: application/json').

Add the header and format the outpout.

Answer (score 0):

When everything seems ok but receive 404, check this answer:

***As you know:***
In the Spring MVC you can return view as a `String` or `ModelAndView` object.

***IMPORTANT NOTE:***

In both cases you have to pay attention to **relative/absolute path**:

1. If you declare `/` in the beginning of the view name, you are using **absolute path**.
   Namely it does not matter **class level** `@RequestMapping` and directly introduce itself as the **final view name**.
2. If you **do not** declare `/` in the beginning of the view name, you are using **relative path** (relative to the class path) and therefore it **appends** to the **class level** `@RequestMapping` to construct **final view name**.

So, you have to consider the above notes when use the Spring MVC.

**Example:**
1. create two HTML file `test1.html` and `test2.html` in the `static` folder of spring (boot) structure:
Please note that the **class level** `@RequestMapping` behaves as a **folder** path in the case of **relative** path.

```
--- resources
    --- static
        --- classLevelPath     //behaves as a folder when we use relative path scenario in view names   
            --- test2.html      //this will be used for relative path [case (2)]
        --- test1.html          //this will be used for absolute path [case (1)]
```

2. create a controller class like as the below. This example shows different cases with return `String` and `ModelAndView` in both **relative** and **absolute** path.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classLevelPath")
public class TestController {

    //case(1)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelAbsolutePath1")
    public String absolutePath1(Model model){
        //model.addAttribute();
        //...
        return "/test1.html";  
    }

    //case(1)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelAbsolutePath2")
    public ModelAndView absolutePath2(Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/test1.html");
        //modelAndView.addObject()
        //....
        return modelAndView; 
    }

    //case(2)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelRelativePath1")
    public String relativePath1(Model model){
        //model.addAttribute();
        //...
        return "test2.html";
    }

    //case(2)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelRelativePath2")
    public ModelAndView relativePath2(Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test2.html");
        //modelAndView.addObject()
        //....
        return modelAndView;  
    }


}
```

**Note:**
You can specify the suffix of your view files by a `ViewResolver` (for example `InternalResourceViewResolver` or `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html` in the `appliction.properties` file of Spring Boot and do not declare `.html` suffix in the above code.

Best Regard